# Highlighting certain parts of matrix without TikZ

Tags: matrices, highlighting, tikz-matrix, blkarray

I have a matrix, given in the following snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
\begin{blockarray}{ccccccccccc}
    & \O & 12 & 12,34 & 13 & 13,24 & 14 & 14,23 & 23 & 24 & 34 \\
      \begin{block}{c[cccccccccc]}
           01 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        01,23 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        01,24 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        01,34 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to have a green box around the first 7 columns of the matrix, and a red box around the other 3 columns. I've tried implementing the solution given in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix) post, but I think that using blkarray inside of TikZ is causing a problem.

Is there an alternative I can use? Or perhaps a way to use TikZ which will work?

Comment: You could use a Ti*k*Z matrix instead of `blkarray`.

Comment: @Skillmon I'm open to doing that, but I don't know how to label the rows and columns without `blkarray`

Answer (score 3):

[image]

with `tikz` ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, fit, matrix}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,
    every label/.append style={label distance=6pt, inner sep=0pt}
                        ]
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes={minimum width=2em, minimum height=3ex,
                    text depth=2pt, inner xsep=1pt, anchor=base},
             column sep=4pt,
             row sep=0pt,
             ]
{|[label=left:01,
  label=$\emptyset$]|   1 & |[label=12]| 1
                                & |[label={12,34}]| 0
                                    & |[label=13]| 0
                                        & |[label={13,24}]| 0
                                            & |[label=14]| 0
                                                & |[label={14,23}]| 0
                                                    & |[label=23]| 1
                                                        & |[label=24]| 1
                                                            & |[label=34]| 1 \\
 |[label=left:{01,23}]| 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 |[label=left:{01,24}]| 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 |[label=left:{01,34}]| 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
};
\draw (m-1-1.north west) + ( 3pt,0) -| (m-4-1.south west) -- + ( 3pt,0);
\draw (m-1-9.north east) + (-3pt,0) -| (m-4-9.south east) -- + (-3pt,0);
%
\node[draw=red, inner sep=1pt, fit={([xshift=5pt] m-1-1.north west) (m-4-6)}] {};
\node[draw=green, inner sep=1pt, fit={(m-1-7) ([xshift=-5pt] m-4-9.south east)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for not using my package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you are welcome! and thank you very much! however i like to use your packages (actually i can live in `latex` without them)  when know how :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, just now i stuck using `tabularx` which has 26 columns. i cant remember (and find here) how to increase number of columns and now i'm not able to enjoy to chat room to ask for help ... my bad

Comment: why is the number of columns an issue, tabularx hasn't got any maximum other than generic tex limits has it?

Comment: because the width of cell are corrupted. can we discus this in chat room? how i can reach you in it?

Comment: just show up here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends

Answer (score 2):

It is simple with `pstricks`: you define the opposite vertices of a frame as empty nodes (`\pnode` command) at the relevant places in the matrix and use the `\psframe` command. I also added some improvements to your matrix:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{blkarray, array, bigstrut, makebox}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\psset{linejoin=1}
    \begin{equation}\setlength{\BAextrarowheight}{3pt}\bigstrutjot = 4pt
\begin{blockarray}{cr*{9}{c}}
    & \varnothing & 12 & \makebox*{12}{12{,}34} & 13 & \makebox*{12}{13{,}24} & 14 & \makebox*{12}{14{,}23} & 23 & 24 & 34 \\
      \begin{block}{c[r*{9}{c}]}
           01 &\enspace \pnode[-1ex, 2.1ex]{A} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \pnode[-1ex, 2.1ex]{C} 1 & 1 & 1 \bigstrut[t]\\
        01{,}23 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        01{,}24 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        01{,}34 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\pnode[1ex, -0.6ex]{B} & 1 & 1 & 1 \pnode[1ex, -0.6ex]{D}\bigstrut[b]\enspace \\
      \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\end{equation}
\psframe[linecolor=IndianRed](A)(B)
\psframe[linecolor=DarkSeaGreen](C)(D)
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An option based on these examples: [Highlight elements in the matrix in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436476/154390), [colored upper triangular matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/441693/154390).

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing,fit,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Global config
        Highlight/.style={
            draw,
            fill,
            rounded corners=2pt,
            fill opacity=0.05,
        },
        Delimiter/.style={
            left delimiter=[,
            right delimiter=],
            inner xsep=-1pt,
            %inner ysep=-1pt,
        }
    ]

    \matrix[matrix of nodes,align=center,nodes in empty cells,] at (0,0) (M){ % Matrix contents  
    & \O & 12 & 12,34 & 13 & 13,24 & 14 & 14,23 & 23 & 24 & 34 \\
    01 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    01,23 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    01,24 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    01,34 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    };

    \begin{scope}[on background layer] 
         %FOR MATRIX M
         %To delimit internal braces
         \node[Delimiter,fit=(M-2-2)(M-5-11)](Internal){};
         %To delimit internal area groups
         \draw[Highlight,red](M-5-2.south west) rectangle (M-2-8.north -| M-1-8.east);
         \draw[Highlight,green](M-5-9.south west) rectangle (M-2-11.north east);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```